# Applying a function over a list of strings and creating new columns

Tags: r

I want to apply a function to a list of strings, and simultaneously create a new column in the same data frame for each string, in which to store the new data. I'm using R.

For a single string/variable, the code looks like this. The function searches for a string in a column, which is why the function is applied to a string:

```
dt$Q1.var1 <- myfunction("var1")
```

I've tried various configurations, but here are a couple that don't work. First, the following creates new columns but fills every column with the same values. I know based on my data that this is not right:

```
varlist = c("var1","var2","var3") 
Q1list = rep("Q1", length(varlist)

     dt[,paste(Q1list, varlist, sep".")] <- sapply(dt[,varlist], function(x) myfunction(x))
```

My second attempt is to use a `for`loop, but with the same results (new columns with new values, but all the same values).

```
for (var in varlist) {
  dt[,paste(Q1list, varlist, sep=".")] <- myfunction(varlist)
}
```

The `for` loop also produces 50 warnings, all the same:

```
1: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  ... :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any help would be much appreciated. It seems I am missing a crucial component to iterating the function over the strings, somehow. I haven't been able to find anything addressing this question on stackoverflow or elsewhere, though this may be because I'm lacking the language to express the problem in searchable terms.

Comment: Is your column of type character? If so, `dt$new_col <- str_func(dt$str_col)`, (where `str_func` is your function) should work. This is because R is vectorized by nature. Also as a note, unless your `function("var1")` is pseudo-code, that doesn't really make sense as the use of `function` in R is restricted

Comment: Last things first - that was meant to say "myfunction" rather than "function," my mistake. But I don't see how your reply solves my problem of running through a list of strings (str_col) and creating new columns with that same list. I'm already able to do this line by line with the first block of code (where you found the typo), so I could do it manually by plugging in each new_col name and each str_col separately. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do the job.

Comment: Fair I may have misunderstood - what might be helpful is including an example of your input and desired output. It is specifically not clear what the data type/structure of your input is